# Mostrar solamente una clave en una matriz con dos claves

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript

Tengo unos datos como estos, los cuales tienen dos claves. En este caso `janeth` y `v3swhmue05`:

```
"janeth,v3swhmue05": [
   {
     id: 1,
     nombre: "janeth",
     hash: "v3swhmue05"
   }, 
   { 
     id:2,
     nombre: "janeth",
     hash: "v3swhmue05"
   }
]
```

En el HTML tengo algo como esto:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of confPersoDocenteClas | keyvalue">  
   <div>
         <h5 class="card-title">{{item.key}}</h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

Lo cual en el componente me muestra esto:

```
janeth,v3swhmue05
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que solo me muestre la primera clave? que, en este caso, es `janeth`.

Comment: En realidad es una única clave lo que tienes, la cadena `janeth,v3swhmue05`, y no dos como estás indicando en el título. Que esta cadena contenga dos cosas separadas por una coma es algo con lo que tendrás que trabajar como con cualquier cadena de caracteres. ¿No será que quieres que se muestren los dos elementos que contiene dicha clave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un `split` y seleccionar el elemento de la posición 0:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of confPersoDocenteClas | keyvalue">  
       <div>
             <h5 class="card-title">{{item.key.split(',')[0]}}</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias! Me  sirvió mucho

Answer (score 3):

Tus datos solo contienen una clave llamada `janeth,v3swhmue05`, bajo la cual existen dos registros.

Si lo que quieres es iterar los dos registros de dicha clave, entonces deberás anidar el bucle de la siguiente manera:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of confPersoDocenteClas | keyvalue">
  <h5 class="card-title">Índice: {{item.key}}</h5>
  <div *ngFor="let contenido of item.value">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{contenido.nombre}} ({{ contenido.id }})</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en la siguiente URL:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-breeze-c2kll?file=/src/app/app.component.html